# npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer webpack@"1 || 2" from loaders@1.1.3

Tags: reactjs, webpack

```
 Using Node version 16.14.2
 npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.88.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
    npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.88.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer webpack@"1 || 2" from loaders@1.1.3
    npm ERR! node_modules/loaders
    npm ERR!   dev loaders@"^1.1.3" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Expecting no npm error while making npm install with below content in package.json in react project

```
     "webpack": "^5.88.2",
     "loaders": "^1.1.3",
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `loaders`. It's from 2017, and as the error says, compatible with Webpack 1 and 2 only. Not 5.